# Dynamic input fields displaying incorrect value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jtable

I am using JTable to display form data and seem to be having a problem where the custom inputs are all displaying the value of the first input. What should happen, is each input should hold it's own value based on the selected datepicker data.

However, if I click the second input, this displays the correct date in the input, but when I click button, the value that is returned is the value of input 1.

All I am trying to do is, get the value of the input on the click event.

I would be grateful if someone could shed some light as to where I have gone wrong as I am still learning JTable and jQuery. Many thanks.

```
//function to amend and destroy boxes
$(function() {

  //Prepare jTable
  $('#setDestScheduleShow').jtable({
    title: 'Box Destruction Schedule',
    paging: true,
    pageSize: 5,
    pageSizes: [5, 10, 25, 50, 100, 250, 500],
    messages: {
      pagingInfo: 'Showing {0} to {1} of {2} records',
      editRecord: 'Edit Box Record'
    },
    sorting: true,
    defaultSorting: 'destroy_date ASC',
    actions: {
      listAction: '../users/destroySchedDisp.php?action=list',
      //createAction: '../users/destroySchedDisp.php?action=create',
      //updateAction: '../users/destroySchedDisp.php?action=update',
      //deleteAction: '../users/destroySchedDisp.php?action=delete'
    },
    fields: {
      Id: {
        key: true,
        title: 'Id',
        width: '2%',
        list: false
      },
      customer: {
        title: 'Co Ref',
        width: '10%',
        list: false
      },
      intake_date: {
        title: 'Intake Date',
        width: '14%',
        type: 'date',
        displayFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
      },
      destroy_date: {
        title: 'Destroy Date',
        width: '14%',
        type: 'date',
        displayFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'

      },
      custref: {
        title: 'Box No',
        width: '14%'
      },
      amend: {
        title: 'Amend Date',
        width: '12%',
        sorting: false,
        type: 'date',
        display: function(data) {
          return '<input type="text" name="MyName" onclick="dpicker();" />'; **<--- THIS IS THE INPUT**
        }
      },
      sendbtn: {
        title: 'Update',
        width: '12%',
        sorting: false,
        display: function(data) {
          var $button = $('<input type="button" class="destBtn" name="destUpdBtn" value="Update" />');

          $button.click(function() {
            temp();
          });
          return $button;
        }
      }
    }
  });
  $('#setDestScheduleShow').jtable('load');
});

function dpicker() {

        $('input[name="MyName"]').datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        yearRange: '2011:2037',
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        minDate: 0,
        defaultDate: null
      });

    };

function temp() {
        var $temper = $('input[name="MyName"]').val();
        alert($temper);

}
```

Comment: What does your html look like? Do all of your inputs have name="MyName"? or is that just to illustrate?

Comment: @thatjuan This is what is in fierbug html: <input id="dp1414166596969" class="hasDatepicker" type="text" onclick="dpicker();" name="MyName"> id's are assigned by JTable. Thanks

Comment: I'm not too familiar with jTable, but I think the selector being used is odd "input[name="MyName"]".

Comment: I cannot assign an id because JTable creates them dynamically. I have tried assigning a class, but still the same. I think it is because the way it is structured, there is only ever 1 name so it is always finding the same one. Not sure though. Just a thought. Thanks